# Softmax function doesn't predict

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, softmax

I have a NN and in my last layer output before softmax I have `17` numbers (each number for every patient).
These are the numbers:

```
[[   -534.2598 ]
 [-255322.64   ]
 [-251120.55   ]
 [-248624.     ]
 [   -538.3214 ]
 [-255104.42   ]
 [-248609.89   ]
 [-253180.05   ]
 [-247280.56   ]
 [   -539.3145 ]
 [   -538.0261 ]
 [   -540.1227 ]
 [-254579.94   ]
 [   -532.4342 ]
 [   -531.34863]
 [   -528.2402 ]
 [-259635.69   ]]
```

now, the ground truth for these numbers are:

```
[[0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1]]
```

Now it can be seen very clearly that the input for the softmax is a good input to predict the ground truth - each time the number is  bigger than `-1000` - we know the answer is `0`.
    For some reason the softmax function can't learn a simple thing like that and always gives the answer (after doing "argmax" to the output) of

```
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...]
```

Interestingly, it doesn't make mistake when the input has positive numbers as predictors for `0` and negative as predictors for `1`, and get `100%` accuracy.

More interestingly , it also does make mistake when in both groups the numbers are positive.

Now, my only question is - why is it so hard for my softmax to distinguish between `2` types of classes when it's so clear for human. I feel I made some basic mistake in my softmax.

What do I miss?

Thank you!

(Yeah sorry first question here ever, stackoverflow tortured me with this code format so sorry if the post looks strange)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about other things, but softmax can't predict multiple labels. Sum of your softmax layer is 1(by mathematical design of softmax function) which means that with softmax you can have only one answer(only one 1 at output and other zeroes). So expected output for softmax can be

> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]

but no

> [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]

Try for example sigmoid layer instead if you are interested in multi label classification.

Comment: oh no I meant that "[[0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1]]" is the output I wanted to get after "argmax" (each number here is the output for each patient) while I get only 17 zeros (one zero for each patient)